# Concourse git-prs error run check step: check: resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

Concourse pipeline has below git-prs resource

```
- name: git-prs
  type: pull-request
  source:
    repo: ((repo.id))
    uri: ((repo.uri))
    access_token: ((repo.access_token))
    private_key: ((repo.deploy_key))
    only_mergeable: true
```

Getting error as

**git-prs  errored  run check step: run check step: check: resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1
stderr:
failed to unmarshal request: json: unknown field "only_mergeable"**

If I comment only_mergeable then getting the error in private_key step as

**git-prs  errored  run check step: run check step: check: resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1
stderr:
failed to unmarshal request: json: unknown field "private_key"**

Please note that this was working fine till 22-Jan-2024.  No changes done in Pipeline after that as well no change in keys.  I assume no expiry date for Private key as well.  Let me know what I am missing here?
Concourse version - 6.7.6

Comment: What is the `pull-request` resource type? Maybe you have it unpinned, and they just changed something in the `source` block?

Comment: `  - name: pull-request
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: teliaoss/github-pr-resource` - Is this related to authenticate issue?